# tmux active on shell startup gives nested tmux session for root

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, tmux, zshrc

I am using zsh together with tmux. I added to my user's  .zshrc the following lines to auto start tmux every time i open a terminal.

```
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```

To get the same theme and settings for my root account i created a symlink between root its .zshrc and my own.

Now every time i login as root a new tmux session starts within the current one and a new shell window. Running pstree give this output:

```
tmux--zsh--sudo--su--tmux
    |-zsh-pstree
```

I wonder why the last tmux process does not spawn a new shell? I expected it to be like

```
tmux--zsh--sudo--su--tmux--zsh
    |-zsh-pstree
```

With the bash and its default settings logging in as root does not give me a new shell window. How do i need to change the  setup to get this behaviour and how do i not start a new tmux session when changing to root?

Comment: This should be posted on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Clearly, you do not want to start a new `tmux` session with *every* interactive shell, so `.zshrc` is the wrong place to run `exec tmux`. Instead, you should configure your terminal emulator to run `tmux` as its default process for a new window.